# How to get value of Laravel URL parameter even without embed it in Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.6, PHP 7.1, XAMPP. I have URL which contain a values from one controller and defined before. 
My question, how to get the last value in laravel URL without passing a value before. My code below will show the problem as well.

This is my Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#student_table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{{ route('leads.getdata') }}",
        "columns":[
            { "data": "group_id" },
            { "data": "customer_id" },
            { "data": "customer_id" },
            { "data": "action", orderable:false, searchable: false},
            { "data":"checkbox", orderable:false, searchable:false}
        ]
    });
```

My route:

```
Route::get('leads/getdata', 'Controller@getdata')->name('leads.getdata');
```

Controller.php

```
function getdata(Request $request)
{
    //$id = $request->input('id');
    $students = GroupCustomer::select('id', 'name', 'address')->where('user_id', '=', $id);
    return Datatables::of($students)
        ->addColumn('action', function($student){
            return '<a href="/customers/'.$student->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary eye" id="'.$student->id.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete" id="'.$student->id.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>';
        })
        ->addColumn('checkbox', '<input type="checkbox" name="student_checkbox[]" class="student_checkbox" value="{{$id}}" />')
        ->rawColumns(['checkbox','action'])
        ->make(true);
}
```

The current URL is : `http://localhost:8000/leads/6` as I need to get '6' value and pass it to the query to get the name, address of that user. currently, it working without 'where' statement. However, I want to show only the name and address of user_id = '6'.

Is there a way to get this '6' value without change anything in Ajax and route as well ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but I think you are asking about [route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters)?  You can also use [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding), so you will get the whole `GroupCustomer` model without any query in your controller. Check those docs, do they help?  If not, try to clarify your question, I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: yes, exactly. I tried to binding data in the route to pass them to the next page, but it keep show me an error, may u tell me how we can binding the data in this Ajax script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was solved by binding the data, actually the problem was from binding the data. Dom . was not working well so once I fix the problem of binding it working well.

this is my Ajax code after fix the problem of DOM :

```
 var id = document.getElementById("customer_id").value;

                       $('#student_table').DataTable({

                           "processing": true,
                           "serverSide": true,
                           ajax: {
                               url: "{!! route('leads.getdata') !!}",
                               type: "GET",
                               data: {id, id},
                               dataType: "JSON"
                           },
                           "columns":[
                               { "data": "group_id" },
                               { "data": "customer_id" },
                               { "data": "customer_id" },
                               { "data": "action", orderable:false, searchable: false},
                               { "data":"checkbox", orderable:false, searchable:false}
                           ]
                       });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change route to:

```
Route::get('leads/{id}', 'Controller@getdata')->name('leads.getdata');
```

Change controller to:

```
function getdata(Request $request, $id) {
    //$id = $request->input('id');

    $students = GroupCustomer::select('id', 'name', 'address')->where('user_id', '=', $id)->get();
    return Datatables::of($students)
        ->addColumn('action', function($student){
            return '<a href="/customers/'.$student->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary eye" id="'.$student->id.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete" id="'.$student->id.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>';
        })
        ->addColumn('checkbox', '<input type="checkbox" name="student_checkbox[]" class="student_checkbox" value="{{$id}}" />')
        ->rawColumns(['checkbox','action'])
        ->make(true);
}
```

*I think it's not possible to achieve what you want without touching ajax or route.*

Comment: I got this line: 

{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":0,"recordsFiltered":0,"data":[],"queries":[{"query":"select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `group_customers` where `customer_id` = ?) count_row_table","bindings":["1"],"time":0.48},{"query":"select `id`, `name`, `address` from `group_customers` where `user_id` = ?","bindings":["6"],"time":0.32}],"input":[]}

As u can see, the 'where' condition is empty. How to get and pass the value of  "bindings":["6"]  to $id, so i can use it as variable and assign it later to 'where' statement

Comment: I updated code. You have to add ->get() like: $students = GroupCustomer::select('id', 'name', 'address')->where('user_id', '=', $id)->get(); and also you can make it shorter to use it like: $students = GroupCustomer::where('user_id', $id)->get(['id', 'name', 'address']);